# Select Command parameter issue

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, executescalar

How do I properly declair a parameter in the code below.  Im getting underlines on "SelectCommand" Im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
 public int GetTotalNumberOfAprovedPictureIds(string SexType)
    {
        string strConectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseConnection"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1 FROM MEMBERS INNER JOIN Picture ON MEMBERS.MemberID = Picture.MemberID WHERE (Picture.PicAproval = 1) AND (Picture.PicArchive = 0) AND (MEMBERS.MemberSex = @dSexType)", conn);


        object oValue = oCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        oCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dSexType", SqlDbType.Text);
        oCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@dSexType"].Value = SexType;

        conn.Close();

        if (oValue == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(oValue);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your IDE is smart enough no to pop up the list of properties, if not available. How did you write such statements?

Comment: +1 to offset random -1 (with no explanation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a couple of things wrong;

1) You are adding the parameter AFTER you execute the query

2) You are using the SelectCommand property when you don't need to. In fact, you are probably confusing this with a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx) object, which does have a SelectCommand property.

Instead, try:

```
    public int GetTotalNumberOfAprovedPictureIds(string SexType)
    {
        string strConectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseConnection"];

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS INNER JOIN Picture ON MEMBERS.MemberID = Picture.MemberID WHERE (Picture.PicAproval = 1) AND (Picture.PicArchive = 0) AND (MEMBERS.MemberSex = @dSexType)", conn))
            {
                oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlParameter myParam = oCommand.Parameters.Add("@dSexType", SqlDbType.Text);
                myParam.Value = SexType;

                object oValue = oCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                if (oValue == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(oValue);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I'd strongly urge you to use a ["USING"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement when dealing with SqlConnection, SqlCommand and similar objects. It will ensure your connection is closed and disposed as soon as it leaves the scope, including after an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) does not have a property or field called `SelectCommand`. Just get rid of it:

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@dSexType", SqlDbType.Text);
oCommand.Parameters["@dSexType"].Value = SexType;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@dSexType", SqlDbType.Text);
oCommand.Parameters["@dSexType"].Value = SexType;
```

`SelectCommand` has no such properties. Use directly like the above.